# SSL Error 113 (SSL version error or cipher mismatch)

Tags: tomcat, ssl, keystore

I have created a keystore for a client.cer SSL certificate file. And added those configuration to my tomcat server.xml.

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
               keystoreFile="/home/isuruanu/myclient"
               keystorePass="changeit" />
```

Now when I try to access my local tomcat using **https:127.0.0.1:8443** it gives me and error saying
SSL Error 113 (SSL version error or cipher mismatch)

What can be the possible root causes if I want to dig and find the solutions.

I already check clearing browser caches, didnt help though.

Comment: What client are you using? Browser? Version?